# lock escalations and EAV model in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, locking, entity-attribute-value

We are developing a web application which allows to store trees of objects with user-defined schema. EAV model is used to implement this scenario in SQL Server. It leads to a single object being stored in a constant number of tables (i.e. "object table", "values table", "entities table", "attributes table" and so on). Our workload assumes periodic imports of object trees from different data sources (Excel and a bunch of proprietary formats), which can be quite large. To ensure consitency of imported trees (keep in mind it's EAV) we do it in one big transaction. Also users often delete results of such imports, which can be very resource intensive.

These inserts and deletes spawn a large number of locks on EAV tables which results in eventual lock escalations (after escalation threshold is reached). This transaction exclusively locks EAV tables making it impossible for users to even read the data, which is not involved in a transaction from the user standpoint (all the data, in fact).

I can think of only 2 ways to mitigate this problem

- Disable lock escalation on EAV tables. This one I strongly
  dislike because of uncertainty it brings to memory consumption
  and lock manager       operations.
- Allow READ COMMITED SNAPSHOT. This isolation level    allows
  nonblocking    reads (with MVCC overhead), but still I can't issue updates on the whole table    because AFAIK escalations are there to stay
  and writers will block    writers.

Can anyone kindly tell me if there are other options to have large INSERTs/DELETEs not block entire tables or may be I got something wrong?